# DDD and blameable

Tags: php, domain-driven-design

How do you handle situation with blameable in the DDD way? 
Ofcourse we can ignore some things, but i think that when entity need some tracking (creator, updater, time updated / created) it should be in the class that actually performs some actions on entity. 
For example we have post and user, what whould be the correct way?

```
$post = new Post();
$post->create(); // here we can set some created_id and 
other attributes by using mixins or traits like some fw do
```

Or it is better like this:

```
$user->createPost($post);
$user->update($post);
```

As for me second is better, even when we need to track changes that does not apply to post directly, for example:

```
$post->doSomethingWithPost();
$user->updatePost($post);
```

Seems like blameable just throws out one important entity - user who manages some things on entities. 
Ofcourse we should not overcomplicate things, but usually when blameable is implemented, entity from which you will get id is a logged in user, that is incorrect to the bounded context. 
Here it is some Blogging Context, where user of this context updates post and not some authenticated user.

Whats your thoughts on this one? Is there some similar questions that i maybe missed?

Comment: It's ironic how first you're creating a Post and then invoke the _create_ method on the newly created post...

Comment: well yes, i just showed to cases and asked how blameable looks from DDD side, in real world it would be $user->createPost($post) or $post = new Post(new Author()) $post->create(). Main question here is about blameable.

Comment: To me, "blameable" seems to be an application concern that is not found in the model of your domain, and should therefore be handled out of the domain model.  With a straight-forward repository implementation, tracking of creator/updater/time updated/created etc is almost trivial.

Answer (score 0):

All your examples seem like they are not designed with the DDD principles in mind. The first indicator to me is the usage of a `$user` variable. In 99% of the cases this is too generic to really capture the intent of a given Model. I think there are hidden concepts that would first have to be made explicit. I think along the lines of `RegisteredAuthor` and `Administrator`. At least that's what I understand from:

> Here it is some Blogging Context, where user of this context updates post and not some authenticated user.

Another question is how can a "user of this context" not be authenticated? How do you know who he is?

In general in an application that explicitly requires User management we normally have something like an **IdentityContext** as a supporting **Sub Domain**. In the different contexts we then have other Models like `Author` or `BlogAdministrator` holding a reference to the User's identity (`UserId`) from the IdentityContext. [The Red Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321834577) has some nice examples on how to implement this.

To answer the question on **how to track who changed something and when**:

This concept is also referred to as **Auditability**, which in most revenue relevant parts of system is actually a must once your organization is reaching a certain size. In this scenario I actually always recommend an **Event Sourcing** approach since it comes with auditability batteries included.

In your case it would actually be enough to either capture the executing `UserId` as Metadata to the commands like `WritePostCommand` or `ChangePostContentsCommand` or use the `UserId` in a **RequestContext** object that knows about the execution context (who was sending this command, when was it sent, is this user allowed to execute this use case).

You can then, as [Alexander Langer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1757320/alexander-langer) pointed out in the comments, just use this metadata inside your Repositories or Handlers to pass the information to the Aggregates that need it, or could even just send them to an audit log to not pollute your Domain Model with this responsibilities.

**NOTE**: Generally I would not use the **DoctrineExtensions** like **Blameable** in your Domain Model. They depend heavily on Doctrine's Event system, and you do not want to tie your Model into an Infrastructure concern.

Kind regards